# Break y axis into two giving more importance to small values in faced_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I'm having difficulties setting y-breaks in my code.

The problem is that "real" plot arrives to very high values, so when I plot "low", "mean", "up" and "real" plots in the same facet_grid, it is impossible to see all the lines and uncertainties. Thus, I want to break the y axis of the first plot (real plot), from 750000 (maximum of up, low and mean plots) to 1e14, and starts again from 1e15 to 1.5e15.

In addition, I want different importance to each y-scales. I mean, I want to give more importance (=more space in y) to the low values, giving more yticks, and less importance to high values (for example from 1e15 to 1.5e15, only 2 ticks and very close between them), in order to see all the data in a plot.

Any help?¿? I don't know what to do...

CODE:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x= year)) +
    geom_line(aes(x= year, y = median, colour = Dquant), size = 1) +
    geom_line(aes( y = mean, colour = Dquant), size = 1, linetype="dashed") +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min,
                    ymax = max, fill = Dquant), alpha = 0.3) +

    facet_grid(~sce, scales="free") +

    theme_minimal() +
    theme( axis.title.x = element_blank(),
           axis.title.y = element_blank(),
           legend.title = element_blank(),
           legend.text = element_text(size = 14),
           legend.position="bottom")
```

plots:

Without real
[image: Without real]

With real
[image: With real]

**Data:**

```
    Data <- 
    structure(list(year = c(1997, 1997, 1997, 1998, 1998, 1998, 1999, 
    1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
    2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 
    2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 
    2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
    2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 
    2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 
    2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
    2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 
    2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
    2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018), Dquant = c("1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "1998-2018", 
    "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "1998-2018", "2008-2018", 
    "2008-2018", "2008-2018", "2008-2018"), sce = structure(c(2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    3L), .Label = c("real", "mean", "up", "low"
    ), class = "factor"), median = c(271250.933411761, 174329.842690641, 
    181988.279010382, 176326.661924226, 128322.447002041, 134693.604638111, 
    274986.723864926, 233927.074724176, 218592.867204935, 148779.734316761, 
    143074.499781715, 138605.14387934, 138986.037693604, 140406.834993171, 
    137148.680644009, 237118.679978143, 235327.177239454, 232563.719479456, 
    192520.645814095, 184107.296353477, 188924.610766882, 126242.612950543, 
    116564.164936345, 126142.679882613, 228401.785313612, 231600.864763052, 
    225778.708786399, 157634.684628256, 182620.381594339, 162596.829195135, 
    209609.647874702, 287685.989594668, 222039.329619513, 227218.657799938, 
    229536.354527116, 24052713437.3087, 275127.749195115, 316517.903895436, 
    525767.641837695, 347213.289117941, 379746.499264302, 336654.532566334, 
    55669475529.556, 409213.325193257, 522913.943442896, 906396.752084313, 
    568307.797375571, 523593.790627888, 580768.962810708, 72723342272.8429, 
    707133.893585878, 187300.561798093, 273876.888111204, 204509.914838313, 
    183536.60399367, 206218.037486455, 20633312274.0172, 249886.775275496, 
    197328.548918493, 298241.680770821, 215297.11601296, 194127.02247954, 
    214501.475793396, 22109752413.519, 264744.405297724, 206067.011853416, 
    325971.087455159, 224852.27070726, 200408.965400769, 227563.666986308, 
    26337155102.0573, 286321.383263596, 381055.745058772, 743238.963653956, 
    410020.333630838, 370135.899473898, 418236.650437978, 58099402495.751, 
    536035.150446747, 289455.888318165, 457319.155632952, 311353.245919098, 
    279102.802335806, 314680.011668731, 42170238120.2681, 413058.235362188, 
    180223.81576812, 228907.532444965, 198812.22107376, 174444.347359958, 
    199108.719109354, 22040096077.1082, 261646.314783439, 176943.664778089, 
    198266.511073489, 200036.565929875, 176780.88386372, 203807.205662623, 
    20358509050.6741, 264847.863281347, 247298.971362715, 281960.090434183, 
    293214.308624952, 257941.517747829, 307517.2239194, 27081019501.5515, 
    391478.682462643, 326063.568077276, 282731.10889422, 421368.649072822, 
    321337.216213794, 457318.609728295, 29796073288.7595, 591108.63326355
    ), mean = c(272345.269911437, 180596.815383997, 170855.016063135, 
    178655.502153251, 142421.910371093, 131686.485787666, 274500.130286522, 
    247461.446076309, 235115.772524758, 148733.094456303, 143432.084877213, 
    140510.197267933, 139197.527174579, 142619.493225591, 137004.723297707, 
    237307.162531229, 238820.975308384, 234020.823135885, 192588.784301406, 
    182060.030595796, 190159.024388065, 126218.368279055, 112088.601395985, 
    126133.779393713, 228512.205381352, 225016.800848212, 224802.630232783, 
    158194.341351618, 187822.312246315, 162606.514573339, 210416.492201143, 
    309748.295357797, 221430.842420298, 223617.793915441, 223903.125325354, 
    9904242352030.65, 260347.569773366, 318244.337883203, 579640.006666561, 
    345346.032505856, 370626.607279363, 332233.945505506, 21491776104474.9, 
    409209.242116443, 523904.60059478, 935075.323382305, 566479.595778939, 
    524678.248681422, 581007.533816242, 35943252213543.2, 723959.418747222, 
    187325.679465279, 259083.409164507, 202843.88926727, 184235.215391617, 
    205097.608470816, 11164970385302.4, 244124.370406846, 197286.064655086, 
    280673.977037158, 211594.093202052, 194185.432587594, 212285.047320748, 
    11989964680622.3, 254972.353149082, 206296.015356819, 333123.396710878, 
    222566.992906555, 200827.593580583, 226822.293863734, 13237495981083.1, 
    285728.077340759, 381571.683615591, 754078.140808609, 408933.259114676, 
    370594.912848239, 419346.460486419, 26288695395864.9, 548020.939606612, 
    287912.19373993, 501175.971126948, 308893.675894856, 278909.329103843, 
    315658.663216274, 18806763489671.7, 412551.998304845, 178939.806962114, 
    243313.283324597, 194457.361164901, 173719.872239641, 197541.850055512, 
    10184636434514.1, 256131.851707848, 177403.34711096, 213524.362512937, 
    196316.544146354, 175735.46737574, 200936.844576894, 9647773937737.83, 
    259807.063924946, 258889.707312201, 323325.068090412, 294039.758260533, 
    257891.806217259, 304292.222386475, 13021141129823.3, 394240.478502324, 
    351870.144130187, 341348.167592571, 433858.444814038, 326115.697814003, 
    454778.534719178, 14830154122741.7, 609740.233404267), min = c(269802.68250335, 
    165026.591496844, 126574.652185937, 174222.995448778, 106050.182129119, 
    119913.570073976, 270807.771046926, 197096.12888566, 212470.753857982, 
    145978.846402085, 106231.362505223, 134193.586498507, 138062.52403115, 
    126503.383887816, 133605.633178661, 235281.59322449, 222230.805547128, 
    228207.174754537, 190964.470905785, 152640.234535017, 187713.601278443, 
    125418.002356213, 86523.5097632671, 124622.780149688, 225262.170020554, 
    179612.356185615, 220612.628877919, 156321.389069322, 160397.044072993, 
    159960.822267813, 206398.31734288, 238358.040385515, 217739.87901193, 
    195753.063592292, 178744.326514639, 327141.444854716, 119721.194379894, 
    313554.265962317, 460829.647364256, 328862.786179365, 315756.176896512, 
    308802.557254049, 603581.269205954, 340043.148814031, 518077.044025802, 
    756208.430696753, 541472.184704768, 497202.755664717, 552030.720382341, 
    702668.693219908, 644077.611924028, 185330.442503585, 148118.250092641, 
    191477.117788122, 181194.047028436, 195196.041501458, 157398.084510526, 
    191753.229994009, 192761.312261542, 150027.56193971, 195080.24083109, 
    191927.456550835, 192398.516865925, 162980.34789673, 182842.545442381, 
    204034.579392594, 281249.906763058, 208657.455282282, 197286.587835601, 
    220924.755350833, 277492.299880875, 264955.905604042, 376842.026856835, 
    604016.132683022, 394661.973303136, 363749.247497405, 411976.760845692, 
    721990.196436554, 509498.941152034, 281467.170953993, 375434.082985228, 
    291194.019192411, 270759.652758784, 305567.665112867, 381585.753116895, 
    367429.586410073, 170502.304570832, 163886.531672811, 174162.179403628, 
    165661.529187133, 181592.565921378, 165493.058079916, 198276.94625014, 
    166460.172541479, 138247.546875601, 177118.869703294, 166720.123597407, 
    179486.297293851, 157491.856834842, 187034.351224574, 232586.815483861, 
    224346.889777313, 276104.401418121, 222214.536423694, 291030.371854759, 
    508016.06397275, 379575.5638416, 308191.383461263, 233500.324498805, 
    394546.510926069, 287999.388168663, 419817.803838022, 454332.119814492, 
    570672.894272458), max = c(278193.62359066, 206980.227162761, 
    191728.978011547, 187880.781166901, 206883.612492436, 138310.027772291, 
    276472.96458244, 331713.593444257, 306077.911224606, 150492.861179863, 
    171564.934557625, 149056.76857344, 141176.325878129, 157723.937507601, 
    140555.87470062, 238945.967349945, 263193.262355733, 243380.322769353, 
    194215.35004985, 196673.259565268, 196175.217916205, 127029.416371267, 
    120585.816723563, 128545.795332452, 231626.404194131, 244623.967187696, 
    228151.280756911, 164062.986138446, 218389.055631467, 166429.2805759, 
    217955.144479359, 429000.568575225, 223544.651843054, 252350.791158743, 
    244507.5310162, 401482091333531, 297208.11128433, 337745.037331985, 
    838917.931942716, 354310.970130017, 418405.714660983, 343045.455351557, 
    866974969584186, 428628.025302966, 538473.648185389, 1130409.68137682, 
    585061.699813275, 566710.336785715, 644921.104512694, 1497677059448270, 
    950787.716188074, 193112.575666243, 308014.186745896, 208886.813804999, 
    194561.544435964, 210253.640904286, 468157790957899, 258256.399357027, 
    207532.244131722, 335569.639438896, 221137.82141271, 197579.56820965, 
    221450.409861303, 502184816065837, 278087.337392696, 212416.557515791, 
    393915.329401621, 233246.578236797, 207220.849556175, 232965.727985277, 
    550487671445547, 296079.713374299, 397189.200940651, 997882.618308808, 
    426914.578558878, 381979.828473857, 457159.156157779, 1078252837711580, 
    617231.26184145, 295488.295870466, 724960.176626616, 323571.296542886, 
    291974.105065125, 338700.290465876, 769494647983116, 424067.319079536, 
    186066.925082783, 345890.088096459, 205127.209809905, 180554.987124241, 
    207977.775446729, 419326651118042, 278520.014245492, 185777.797105331, 
    294181.234660947, 206949.84763535, 181176.08041045, 209595.936803633, 
    398235630184494, 286367.51711188, 328697.656116281, 602828.312140973, 
    331412.517715862, 298274.862967901, 327115.761030605, 537894188568343, 
    417462.29787746, 516263.256323623, 971764.797371761, 543973.525737656, 
    391108.546615316, 571900.099240955, 613951949959179, 852004.250623592
    )), row.names = c(8060L, 8062L, 8064L, 8564L, 8566L, 8568L, 9068L, 
    9070L, 9072L, 9572L, 9574L, 9576L, 10076L, 10078L, 10080L, 10580L, 
    10582L, 10584L, 11084L, 11086L, 11088L, 11588L, 11590L, 11592L, 
    12092L, 12094L, 12096L, 12596L, 12598L, 12600L, 13136L, 13138L, 
    13140L, 13144L, 13146L, 13148L, 13150L, 13712L, 13714L, 13716L, 
    13720L, 13722L, 13724L, 13726L, 14288L, 14290L, 14292L, 14296L, 
    14298L, 14300L, 14302L, 14864L, 14866L, 14868L, 14872L, 14874L, 
    14876L, 14878L, 15440L, 15442L, 15444L, 15448L, 15450L, 15452L, 
    15454L, 16016L, 16018L, 16020L, 16024L, 16026L, 16028L, 16030L, 
    16592L, 16594L, 16596L, 16600L, 16602L, 16604L, 16606L, 17168L, 
    17170L, 17172L, 17176L, 17178L, 17180L, 17182L, 17744L, 17746L, 
    17748L, 17752L, 17754L, 17756L, 17758L, 18320L, 18322L, 18324L, 
    18328L, 18330L, 18332L, 18334L, 18896L, 18898L, 18900L, 18904L, 
    18906L, 18908L, 18910L, 19472L, 19474L, 19476L, 19480L, 19482L, 
    19484L, 19486L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide the dataset by copy and pasting the output of `dput(nsim_data_Dqual_allC_eq)`.

Comment: Here you are, do you think that it is posible? this plot is a part of facet_grid ggplot (the final plot has more rows. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most appropriate is to use the same scale for all your graphs that you compare, and the easiest is to log-transform your data. you can do that with `scale_y_log10`, or (as I suggest) with more control beforehand.

I have chosen a ridiculous base of 1000, which is unusual and also maybe difficult to convey. If they are conceptually different values that you show, consider creating the plots separately with different scales and, if you want to show them in a panel, combine them afterwards, e.g. with `patchwork`

```r
library(tidyverse)

Data <- 
  Data %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(median:max), .funs = log, base = 1000)
ggplot(Data, aes(x= year)) +
  geom_line(aes(x= year, y = median, colour = Dquant), size = 1) +
  geom_line(aes( y = mean, colour = Dquant), size = 1, linetype="dashed") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min,
                  ymax = max, fill = Dquant), alpha = 0.3) +
  facet_grid(~sce, scales="free") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>